# How to write Oracle SQL to reset counter based on the value?

Tags: oracle

How can I reset the counter like below examples (I need to generate counter in the column named "Counter I need to generate"?

[image]

Comment: So what is the logic here? Any value other than 1 resets the counter?

Comment: Can you describe a little more what you're trying to achieve? Maybe include some SQL code that you've tried already? (even if it doesn't produce exactly what you want yet)

Comment: There is an expectation amongst readers that you demonstrate some genuine effort first. If you have already made some effort, then it is important to show that effort (and not merely noting that you have tried lots of things). Long-standing users appreciate that this is surprising to new users, since most other places on the web have no guidelines or standards at all. Please read the Help Centre before asking another question - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like each value larger than 1 resets the counter, is that right?

If so, you could assign a group number first, based on the number of times a value > 1 occurs before the current row (including). So row 1 to 11 will be group 0, 12 and 13 will be group 1, and so on.

Then you can apply the row_number window function to generate the numbering partitioned by that group:

```
with VW_GROUPED as (
  select
    t.*,
    (select count(*) from TheTable x where x.URN <= t.URN and x.GAPNOOFDAYS > 1) as GROUPNO
  from
    TheTable /* <- your table name here */ t)

select
  g.URN,
  g.CUSTOMER_ID,
  g.GAPNOOFDAYS,
  row_number() over (partition by GROUPNO order by URN) as "Counter I need to generate"
from
  VW_GROUPED g
```

Comment: Thanks for your query. Yes it does but also counter needs to be reset if Cust_ID changes as well.

Comment: Then make it `partition by GROUPNO, CUSTOMER_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate example that generates the group in using analytic functions instead of a scalar subquery:

```
with grp as (
select t.*
     , sum(case gapnoofdays when 1 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by customer_id order by urn) grp
  from your_table t
)
select grp.*
     , row_number() over (partition by customer_id, grp order by urn) n
  from grp;
```